# ng build with frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to build an Angular application with Maven/Eclipse and with the frontend-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
<artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.6</version>
<configuration>
    <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
    <!-- where to install npm -->
    <installDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</installDirectory>
</configuration>                
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>install node and npm</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>                        
        </configuration>                        
    </execution>
    <execution>
            <id>npm install</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>npm</goal>
            </goals>
            <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
            <configuration>
                <arguments>install</arguments>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
     </execution>
     <execution>
         <id>prod</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>npm</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
           <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
         </configuration>
         <phase>generate-resources</phase>
      </execution>                                                         
</executions>
</plugin>
```

Normally when maven run ng build, it should generate the compiled files in the dist directory.

Although, as you can see on the following print screen, I haven't the correct result in dist directory.

Can you help me please?

[image]

[image]

Here is the output in console log:

```
[INFO] Running 'npm run-script build' in /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/angular5/tourism
[DEBUG] Executing command line [/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/angular5/tourism/node/node, /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/angular5/tourism/node/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js, run-script, build]
[INFO] 
[INFO] > tourism@0.0.0 build /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/angular5/tourism
[INFO] > ng build
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [0mDate: [1m[37m2018-08-27T07:17:09.657Z[39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mHash: [1m[37m237de58c14f4f60a6461[39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mTime: [1m[37m10899[39m[22mms[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mmain[39m[22m} [1m[32mmain.js, main.js.map[39m[22m (main) 9.45 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mpolyfills[39m[22m} [1m[32mpolyfills.js, polyfills.js.map[39m[22m (polyfills) 227 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mruntime[39m[22m} [1m[32mruntime.js, runtime.js.map[39m[22m (runtime) 5.22 kB [1m[33m[entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mstyles[39m[22m} [1m[32mstyles.js, styles.js.map[39m[22m (styles) 15.7 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mvendor[39m[22m} [1m[32mvendor.js, vendor.js.map[39m[22m (vendor) 2.74 MB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[DEBUG] Exit value 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (default-resources) @ tourism-web ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=78, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=26, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=3, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=75, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=150, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=4}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4:compile
[DEBUG]       classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.6:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.0-beta-4:compile
[DEBUG]       org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-api:jar:2.0.6
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.doxia:doxia-sink-api:jar:1.0-alpha-7
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interactivity-api:jar:1.0-alpha-4
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:1.0-beta-4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.13
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) buildFilters = []
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) escapeWindowsPaths = true
[DEBUG]   (s) includeEmptyDirs = false
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (s) overwrite = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: tourism-guide-web:tourism-web:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) resources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@439a8f59
[DEBUG]   (f) useBuildFilters = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useDefaultDelimiters = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] properties used {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, env.XPC_SERVICE_NAME=org.eclipse.platform.ide.1804, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, env.JAVA_STARTED_ON_FIRST_THREAD_791=1, os.name=Mac OS X, sun.boot.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes, env.TMPDIR=/var/folders/cj/18nnbwrn68v72gpfnc09tpl80000gn/T/, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_77-b03, env.Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.gtmqhZw2K7/Render, project.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8, env.DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.T8gATB7rP7/org.macosforge.xquartz:0, user.name=admin, maven.build.version=Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00), env.USER=admin, env.SHELL=/bin/bash, env.__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x1, env.PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, user.language=fr, sun.boot.library.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib, classworlds.conf=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.launching/launches/m2conf2354967348069411789.tmp, env.XPC_FLAGS=0x0, java.version=1.8.0_77, user.timezone=Europe/Paris, sun.arch.data.model=64, http.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, env.JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_886=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher, java.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, file.separator=/, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug, user.country=FR, java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre, java.vm.info=mixed mode, env.LOGNAME=admin, os.version=10.13.6, path.separator=:, java.vm.version=25.77-b03, java.awt.printerjob=sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob, version.war.plugin=2.1.1, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig, env.APP_ICON_791=../Resources/Eclipse.icns, awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit, socksNonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, user.home=/Users/admin, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.library.path=/Users/admin/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:., java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, node.directory=node, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, gopherProxySet=false, maven.home=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/EMBEDDED, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.java.command=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -B -X -e -e clean install, java.class.path=/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.8.3.20180227-2135/jars/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar, maven.version=3.3.9, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, env.HOME=/Users/admin, java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/cj/18nnbwrn68v72gpfnc09tpl80000gn/T/, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web, env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Cg1179KZLC/Listeners, os.arch=x86_64, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment, java.ext.dirs=/Users/admin/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java, user.dir=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web, line.separator=
, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding=UTF-8, npm.executable=npm, java.specification.version=1.8}
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[DEBUG] resource with targetPath null
directory /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/resources
excludes []
includes []
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ tourism-web ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=2, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=160, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=43, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=3, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=63, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=278, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=6}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-parameter-documenter:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-profile:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-error-diagnostics:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-project:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]          org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-registry:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-descriptor:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-artifact-manager:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-monitor:jar:2.0.9:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-toolchain:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.2:runtime
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.5.5:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.2:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4:compile
[DEBUG]          log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12:compile
[DEBUG]          commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[DEBUG]       com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0:compile
[DEBUG]       junit:junit:jar:3.8.2:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:1.5.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:2.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-incremental:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-api:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-manager:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-compiler-javac:jar:2.2
[DEBUG]   Included: org.apache.xbean:xbean-reflect:jar:3.4
[DEBUG]   Included: log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.12
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web
[DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/classes]
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/main/java]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedSourcesDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/generated-sources/annotations
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile {execution: default-compile}
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) projectArtifact = tourism-guide-web:tourism-web:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.5
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.5
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@439a8f59
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@439a8f59
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ tourism-web ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) buildFilters = []
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) escapeWindowsPaths = true
[DEBUG]   (s) includeEmptyDirs = false
[DEBUG]   (s) outputDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/test-classes
[DEBUG]   (s) overwrite = false
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: tourism-guide-web:tourism-web:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT @ /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (s) resources = [Resource {targetPath: null, filtering: false, FileSet {directory: /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/test/resources, PatternSet [includes: {}, excludes: {}]}}]
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@439a8f59
[DEBUG]   (f) useBuildFilters = true
[DEBUG]   (s) useDefaultDelimiters = true
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] properties used {java.vendor=Oracle Corporation, sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD, env.XPC_SERVICE_NAME=org.eclipse.platform.ide.1804, sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers, env.JAVA_STARTED_ON_FIRST_THREAD_791=1, os.name=Mac OS X, sun.boot.class.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes, env.TMPDIR=/var/folders/cj/18nnbwrn68v72gpfnc09tpl80000gn/T/, java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.runtime.version=1.8.0_77-b03, env.Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.gtmqhZw2K7/Render, project.build.sourceEncoding=UTF-8, env.DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.T8gATB7rP7/org.macosforge.xquartz:0, user.name=admin, maven.build.version=Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T17:41:47+01:00), env.USER=admin, env.SHELL=/bin/bash, env.__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x1, env.PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, user.language=fr, sun.boot.library.path=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib, classworlds.conf=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.launching/launches/m2conf2354967348069411789.tmp, env.XPC_FLAGS=0x0, java.version=1.8.0_77, user.timezone=Europe/Paris, sun.arch.data.model=64, http.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, env.JAVA_MAIN_CLASS_886=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher, java.endorsed.dirs=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed, sun.cpu.isalist=, sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8, file.encoding.pkg=sun.io, file.separator=/, java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification, java.class.version=52.0, org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=debug, user.country=FR, java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre, java.vm.info=mixed mode, env.LOGNAME=admin, os.version=10.13.6, path.separator=:, java.vm.version=25.77-b03, java.awt.printerjob=sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob, version.war.plugin=2.1.1, sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig, env.APP_ICON_791=../Resources/Eclipse.icns, awt.toolkit=sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit, socksNonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, ftp.nonProxyHosts=local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16, user.home=/Users/admin, java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation, java.library.path=/Users/admin/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:., java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/, node.directory=node, java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation, gopherProxySet=false, maven.home=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/EMBEDDED, java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment, sun.java.command=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher -B -X -e -e clean install, java.class.path=/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.8.3.20180227-2135/jars/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar, maven.version=3.3.9, java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification, java.vm.specification.version=1.8, sun.cpu.endian=little, sun.os.patch.level=unknown, env.HOME=/Users/admin, java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/cj/18nnbwrn68v72gpfnc09tpl80000gn/T/, java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/, maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web, env.SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Cg1179KZLC/Listeners, os.arch=x86_64, java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment, java.ext.dirs=/Users/admin/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java, user.dir=/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web, line.separator=
, java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, file.encoding=UTF-8, npm.executable=npm, java.specification.version=1.8}
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[DEBUG] resource with targetPath null
directory /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/test/resources
excludes []
includes []
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ tourism-web ---
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@55f96302]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web
[DEBUG]   (f) buildDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target
[DEBUG]   (f) classpathElements = [/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/test-classes, /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/classes]
[DEBUG]   (f) compileSourceRoots = [/Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/src/test/java]
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerId = javac
[DEBUG]   (f) debug = true
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) failOnError = true
[DEBUG]   (f) forceJavacCompilerUse = false
[DEBUG]   (f) fork = false
[DEBUG]   (f) generatedTestSourcesDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations
[DEBUG]   (f) mojoExecution = org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}
[DEBUG]   (f) optimize = false
[DEBUG]   (f) outputDirectory = /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/test-classes
[DEBUG]   (f) showDeprecation = false
[DEBUG]   (f) showWarnings = false
[DEBUG]   (f) skipMultiThreadWarning = false
[DEBUG]   (f) source = 1.5
[DEBUG]   (f) staleMillis = 0
[DEBUG]   (f) target = 1.5
[DEBUG]   (f) useIncrementalCompilation = true
[DEBUG]   (f) verbose = false
[DEBUG]   (f) mavenSession = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@439a8f59
[DEBUG]   (f) session = org.apache.maven.execution.MavenSession@439a8f59
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[DEBUG] Using compiler 'javac'.
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20.1:test (default-test) @ tourism-web ---
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=0, ConflictMarker.markTime=0, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=111, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=34, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=2, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=76, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=75, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=3}
[DEBUG] org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:jar:2.20.1:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven.surefire:maven-surefire-common:jar:2.20.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.2.1:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.plugin-tools:maven-plugin-annotations:jar:3.3:compile
[DEBUG]       org.apache.maven.surefire:surefire-api:jar:2.20.1:compile
.......................................
.......................................




Checking for jar manifest virtual files...



[INFO] Building jar: /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/target/tourism-web-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[DEBUG] adding directory META-INF/
[DEBUG] adding entry META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
[INFO]
```

Answer (score 2):

on advice from a user, I changed a few things
I updated the extract of the pom.xml I gave

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/angular5/tourism</workingDirectory>
                <!-- where to install npm -->
                <installDirectory>temp</installDirectory>
            </configuration>                
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>                      
                    </configuration>                        
                </execution>
                <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                 </execution>
                 <execution>
                     <id>prod</id>
                     <goals>
                       <goal>npm</goal>
                     </goals>
                     <configuration>
                       <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                     </configuration>
                     <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                  </execution>                                                      
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

in the end I don't obtain what I want in the compiled files dist folder
[image]

I don't see for example all the compiled files of app folder

I found on internet an example of what I should have

[image]

Furthermore, the final objective is to generate a zip file containing all the angular project ressources ans sources that I will embed in a war file (which is generated by a maven sub-module project that contains the web services)
Yet, I don't see where and how embed angular dependencies (or libraries) (that is all the dependencies which are listed under the dependencies property of package.json file)
Here is an extract of the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "tourism",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
```

Furthermore, I note what I obtain in my dist folder, and when comparing with what I found on internet, I wonder if the following files are necessary:

```
-main.js.map
-polyfills.js
-polyfills.js.map
-runtime.js
-runtime.js.map
-style.js
styles.js.map
```

If that can help here is an extract of angular.json file

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "tourism": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "tourism:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "tourism:build:production"
            }
          }
```

And here is my tsconfig.app.json file

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

Here is my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

The maven logs are the following

```
[INFO] > ng build
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] [0mDate: [1m[37m2018-09-03T12:53:22.792Z[39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mHash: [1m[37m4e040e480b1db9055f1d[39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mTime: [1m[37m12939[39m[22mms[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mmain[39m[22m} [1m[32mmain.js, main.js.map[39m[22m (main) 8.32 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mpolyfills[39m[22m} [1m[32mpolyfills.js, polyfills.js.map[39m[22m (polyfills) 226 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mruntime[39m[22m} [1m[32mruntime.js, runtime.js.map[39m[22m (runtime) 5.22 kB [1m[33m[entry][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mstyles[39m[22m} [1m[32mstyles.js, styles.js.map[39m[22m (styles) 15.7 kB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[INFO] [0mchunk {[1m[33mvendor[39m[22m} [1m[32mvendor.js, vendor.js.map[39m[22m (vendor) 2.74 MB [1m[33m[initial][39m[22m[1m[32m [rendered][39m[22m[0m
[DEBUG] Exit value 0
```

And I tried to execute on command line: I obtain the same result

Comment: The console output is

Comment: Finally I found the correct answer. It seems that the generated files in dist folder showed above are enough. All the compiled code from the ".ts" files in  app folder are included in main.js. It must be something new for 6.0.3 version