# Deploy a SpringBoot and Angular app on Heroku

Tags: angular, spring-boot, gradle, heroku

I have a web project consisting of:

- a Spring Boot backend application,
- an Angular client frontend that communicates with the above backend.

The project is hosted on Github with the following file-structure:

```
gradle/
src/
 |-- (Spring sources and resources)
web/
 |-- package.json
 |-- (Angular sources and resources)
build.gradle
gradlew
Procfile
settings.gradle
```

I'd like the application to be deployed to Heroku automatically when changes are pushed to Github.
While this works fine for building the Spring application (because Gradle is detected), I'd like to build the Angular application (using `ng build`) and put it in the `src/main/resources/static` folder, so that the client application is served.

How can I do that ? Because `package.json` is not in the root directory, the Angular application is not detected as a nodejs app and not built.

Comment: thats a nice question. can you share the github repo link ? I want to try it.

Comment: You can find the code at https://github.com/thibseisel/odeon-web.
From the time I posted the question I've found a solution involving custom tasks in Gradle that delegates to NPM (installed with the Node Buildpack). This works but looks a bit slow.

Comment: You may use frontend-maven-plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52037321/ng-build-with-frontend-maven-plugin but I dont think it will make the build faster :) npm dependencies are crazy big and every build will take long. Only I can think of is enabling dependencies https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/ to make build faster.